# How do I allow only read access to Switch item in Openhab?

Tags: openhab

I stumbled across [this](https://community.openhab.org/t/existing-item-types-and-their-reasons/6343/10) post while playing around with Openhab 2.4.0. I was trying to display the state of the switch item (for Hue Bulb) with only read access in the control tab of Paper UI. A simple solution would be to have a different item type with only read access to the switch state (similar to [lockOnly](https://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/capabilities-reference.html#lock-only) capability in smartThings) but I couldn't find examples of someone using the "String" item type either.

I think this is useful when someone just wants to share the state of the device while integrating 3rd party service or maybe allowing access to only one command on the device e.g., only allowing lock but disabling unlock.

I'd appreciate if somebody posted a link to a tutorial which tries to implement similar functionality. I'm new to Openhab and I might be misunderstanding the architecture itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am a bit late, but i will try to gice an answer anyway.
I don't think that there will be some kind of tutorial like you would like to see.

The reason is very simple:
Paper UI is not meant for being used in production as ui.
It is meant to be used for configuration and administration and maintenance.
The control section is in there for testing out stuff without the ned to switch to a user ui, like basic ui or the android app.

For other uis like Basic UI or HABPanel you could solve your problem with a so called `proxy-item`.

This has also been answered in an equivalent way in the openhab community thread you have linked in your question.

Anyways, for others who may find this question, heres a [tutorial/explanation](https://community.openhab.org/t/design-pattern-proxy-item/15991?u=confectrician) for usage of proxy items.